# why I am getting only one result only from the youtube api

Tags: python, django, youtube-data-api

I have a list of video ids as strings of different videos of youtube,but when I am fetching the data for all the video ids I am getting result for only last video.

Here is my code :

```
search_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'
parameter = {
       'key' : settings.YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY,
        'part' : 'snippet',
        'id' : ','.join(video_id)
}

         data = requests.get(search_url,params=parameter)
         results = data.json()['items']
```

In the above code the video_id is a list containing video ids.

I am getting a csv file which which has youtube video urls , and I am taking the video id from it and appending them in video_id list as:

```
rows = []
video_id = []
file = request.FILES["file"].readlines()

for f in file:
    rows.append((f.decode('utf-8')))

for row in rows[0:len(rows)-1]:
     video_id.append((row[-13:]))

video_id.append((rows[len(rows)-1][-11:]))
```

The complete code is :

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rows = []
        video_id = []
        file = request.FILES["file"].readlines()

        for f in file:
            rows.append((f.decode('utf-8')))

        for row in rows[0:len(rows)-1]:
             video_id.append((row[-13:]))

        video_id.append((rows[len(rows)-1][-11:]))
        print(len(video_id))
        for v in video_id:
            print(v)


        search_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'

        parameter = {
            'key' : settings.YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY,
            'part' : 'snippet',
            'id' : ','.join(video_id)
        }

        data = requests.get(search_url,params=parameter)
        results = data.json()['items']
        channel_list = []

        for result in results:
            data = {
                'channel_name' : result['snippet']['channelTitle'] 
            }
            channel_list.append(data)
        for list in channel_list:
            print(list)

        return HttpResponse("Uploaded successfully")
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Comment: Can you share us some video ids that you can't retrieve any information about with YouTube Data API ?

Comment: These are 5 video ids which are present in the video_id list -- HpszyPglBtQ, SMoTOxgMLPg, DxAsqinkmyE, t1DzCEaddAY, BAtXEGANEXY and only the result for last id is comming up.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The error was with the video ids because ids contains \r\n at last.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).